# Python: numpy, pandas, and performing operations on the previous array value (smoothed averages): any way to not use FOR loop? EWMA?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tbh, I'm not really sure how to ask this question. I've got an array of values, and I'm looking to take the smoothed average of these values moving forward. In Excel, the calculation process is:

- average_val_1 = mean average of values through window_size
- average_val_2 = (value at location window_size+1 * window_size-1 + average_val_1) / window_size
- average_val_3 = (value at location window_size+2 * window_size-1 + average_val_2) / window_size

etc., etc.

In pandas and numpy, my code for this is the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'av':np.nan, 'values':np.random.rand(10)})
df = df[['values','av']]

window = 5
df['av'].iloc[5] = np.mean(df['values'][:5])

for i in range(window+1,len(df.index)):
  df['av'].iloc[i] = (df['values'].iloc[i] * (window-1) + df['av'].iloc[i-1])/window
```

Which returns:

```
    values      av
0   0.418498    NaN
1   0.570326    NaN
2   0.296878    NaN
3   0.308445    NaN
4   0.127376    NaN
5   0.381160    0.344305
6   0.239725    0.260641
7   0.928491    0.794921
8   0.711632    0.728290
9   0.319791    0.401491
```

These are the values I am looking for, but there has to be a better way than using **for** loops. I *think* the answer has something to do with using exponentially weighted moving averages, but I'll be damned if I can figure out the syntax to make any sense of that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate moving average using NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313510/how-to-calculate-moving-average-using-numpy).  I'm also a fan of stride tricks - which this answer uses - [https://stackoverflow.com/a/39919709/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39919709/2823755)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the intricacies of the different scipy window functions, but using df.rolling() with one of the non-evenly-weighted windowing functions from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#window-functions may be a place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [ewm](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) such as:

```
window = 5
df['av'] = np.nan
df['av'].iloc[window] = np.mean(df['values'][:window])
df.loc[window:,'av'] = (df.loc[window:,'av'].fillna(df['values'])
                          .ewm(adjust=False, alpha=(window-1.)/window).mean())
```

and you get the same result than with your loop `for`. To be sure it works, column 'av' must be `nan` otherwise the `fillna` with column 'values' will not happen and the value calculted in 'av' will be wrong. The parameter `alpha` in `ewm` is what helps you to weigth the row you are calculating.

Note: while this code does as yours, I would recommend to have a look at this line in your code:

```
df['av'].iloc[5] = np.mean(df['values'][:5])
```

Because of the exclusion of the uppper bound when doing slicing `[:5]`, `df['values'][:5]` is:

```
0    0.418498
1    0.570326
2    0.296878
3    0.308445
4    0.127376
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

so I think that what you should do is `df['av'].iloc[4] = np.mean(df['values'][:5])`. If you agree, then my above  must be slightly changed

```
df['av'].iloc[window-1] = np.mean(df['values'][:window])
df.loc[window-1:,'av'] = (df.loc[window-1:,'av'].fillna(df['values'])
                            .ewm(adjust=False, alpha=(window-1.)/window).mean())
```

Comment: You bloody genius! Thanks mate, that solves so many of my problems!

Comment: @RPM welcome, finally, do you agree with the "Note" part?